# Migrated questions stil link to the old site

Tags: discussion, ros-migration, gazebo-migration

Some migrated questions link to other questions on the old site, *even though* the other question was *also* migrated.

Case in point:

This question [imu filter madguick - is it possible to get enu orientation from ned IMUs?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/79232/9176),

> ... I was looking at this [discussion](http://answers.ros.org/question/200480/imu-message-definition/) and ...

which links to [IMU message definition](https://answers.ros.org/question/200480/imu-message-definition/), on the old site. However, [IMU message definition](https://answers.ros.org/question/200480/imu-message-definition/) was migrated to [IMU message definition](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/64984/9176).

Isn't it possible to script a scraper to check for these old links, check to see if the question was migrated (**and** not cleaned up by the Roomba) and update the the links... or at least provide a list of questions that require editing?